# Emscripten - passing libraries

Tags: emscripten

I am compiling a main C project for firefox OS via Emscripten which has dependency on another crypto library C project.I was able to generate crypto.js file for it.When I am trying to compile main C project, I am getting below warnings.How do I pass the crypto library file(crypto.js) in order to avoid multiple warnings such as below with Emscripten?

warning: unresolved symbol: curve25519_shared
warning: unresolved symbol: crecip_donna
warning: unresolved symbol: fmul_donna

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to generate .bc file of your crypto project and then statically link with your main project ie provide the path of crypto.bc file as a parameter when envoking emcc for your main project.

This is the recommended way for maximizing performance and minimizing size as per emscripten docs.